# Where do values fit in Category of Hask?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

So we have Category of Hask, where:

- Types are the objects of the category
- Functions are the morphisms from object to object in the category.

Similarly for `Functor` we have:

- a Type constructor as the mapping of objects from one category to another
- `fmap` for the mapping of morphisms from one category to another.

Now, when we write program we basically transform values (not types) and it seems that the Category of Hask doesn't talk about values at all. I tried to fit values in the whole equation and came up with the following observation:

- Each Type is a category itself. Ex: Int is a category of all integers.
- Functions from a value to another value of **same type** are morphism of the category. Eg: `Int -> Int`
- Functions from one value to another value of **different type** are functor for mapping values of one type to another.

Now my question is - Do values even make sense in the Category of Hask (or in general category theory)? If yes then any reference to read about it OR if not, then any reason for that.

I hope the question makes sense :)

Comment: @AndrewC: So at another level each object in a cateogry itself can be category? Sounds like its categories all the way down :)

Comment: For in introduction to how you can consider the integers as a category, read [this wikiversity article](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Category_Theory/Monoids). It's not categories all the way down, but it might be categories all the way up!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

(I'll use words with their meaning from maths/category theory rather than programming, unless I `mark it as code`.)

### One category at a time

One of the big ideas of category theory is to treat large complex things as a point, so, true to form the set/group/ring/class/category of all integers is considered a single point when you're thinking of the category Hask.

Similarly, you could have a very complicated function on integers, but it's just considered a single element (point/arrow) of a collection (set/class) of morphisms.

The first thing you do in category theory is ignore the detail. So the category Hask doesn't care that Int can be considered a category - that's at a different level. Int is just a point (object) in Hask.

## One level down

Every monoid is a category with one object. Let's use that.

### How are the integers a category?

There's more than one answer to this (since the integers are a monoid under addition and a monoid under multiplication). Let's do addition:

You can consider the integers as a category with a single object, and the morphisms are functions such as (+1), (+2), (subtract 4).

You have to hold in your head that I'm considering the integer 7 as the number 7 but using the representation (+7) to make it appear to be a category. The laws of category theory deliberately **don't** say your morphisms have to be functions, but it's clearer that something's a category if it has the structure of a set of functions containing identity and closed under composition.

Any monoid makes a single-object category in the same way as we've just done with the integers.

### Functors from the integers?

A function `f` from the integers as a category under the operation `+`, to some other type with an operation `£` that forms a category could only be a functor if you had `f(x+y) = f(x) £ f(y)`. (This is called a monoid homomorphism). Most functions aren't morphisms.

### Example morphism

`String`s are a monoid under `++`, so they're a category.

```
len :: String -> Int
len = length
```

`len` is a monoid morphism from `String` to `Int`, because `len (xs ++ ys) = len xs + len ys`, so if you're considering (`String`,`++`) and (`Int`,`+`) as category, `len` is a functor.

### Example non-morphism

(`Bool`,`||`) is a monoid, with `False` as the identity, so it's a one-object category. The function

```
quiteLong :: String -> Bool
quiteLong xs = length xs > 10
```

isn't a morphism because `quiteLong "Hello "` is `False` and `quiteLong "there!"` is also `False`, but `quiteLong ("Hello " ++ "there!")` is `True`, and `False || False` is not `True`.

Because `quiteLong` isn't a morphism, it's not a functor either.

## What's your point, Andrew?

My point is that **some** Haskell types can be considered categories, but not all functions between them are morhpisms.

We don't think of the categories at different levels at the same time (unless you're using both categories for some weird purpose), and there's deliberately no theoretical interaction between the levels, because there's deliberately no detail on the objects and morphisms.

This is partly because category theory took off in maths to provide a language to describe Galois theory's lovely interaction between finite groups/subgroups and fields/field extensions, two apparently *completely* different structures that turn out to be closely related. Later, homology/homotopy theory made functors between topological spaces and groups that turn out to be both fascinating and useful, but the main point is that the objects and the morphisms are allowed to be very different to each other in the two categories of a functor.

(Normally category theory comes into Haskell in the form of a functor from Hask to Hask, so in practice in functional programming the two categories are the same.)

### So... what exactly is the answer to the original question?

> - Each Type is a category itself. Ex: Int is a category of all integers.

If you think of them in particular ways. See PhilipJF's answer for details.

> - Functions from a value to another value of same type are morphism of the category. Eg: `Int -> Int`

I think you mixed up the two levels. Functions can be morphisms in Hask, but not all functions `Int -> Int` are Functors under the addition structure, for example `f x = 2 * x + 10` isn't a functor between Int and Int, so it's not a category morphism (another way of saying functor) from (`Int`,`+`) to (`Int`,`+`) but it is a morphism `Int -> Int` in the category Hask.

> - Functions from one value to another value of different type are functor for mapping values of one type to another.

No, not all functions are functors, for example `quiteLong` isn't.

> Do values even make sense in the Category of Hask (or in general category theory)?

Categories don't have values in category theory, they just have objects and morphisms, which are treated like vertices and directed edges. The objects don't have to have values, and values aren't part of category theory.

Comment: actually...the integers could be regarded as a category in other ways--for example they are a total order.  But, there are also ways of regarding *all* types as categories such that *all function are functorial*.  The most famous is perhaps to to look at the category induced by the partial order of "definedness" on each type (this is the approach of denotational semantics).  You might also think of "sets" or "types" as "discrete categories" where all the arrows are identities--in which case all functions are functors, but then this generalizes to "higher inductive types" a la HoTT.

Comment: @PhilipJF I wanted to not like what you said because you disproved "Some aren't really categories because they have no sensible category structure" (which I've edited to point to your answer instead), but what you've said was too interesting and enlightening do I've had to upvote it. :) I assert that the discrete category isn't a useful one, but the definedness partial ordering _is_, and you explained the whole thing very well in your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

As I commented on Andrew's answer (which is otherwise very good) , you *can* regard values in a type as objects of that type as a category, and regard functions as functors.  For completeness, here are two ways:

### Sets as Boring Categories

One of the most commonly used tools in mathematics is a "setoid"--that is, a set with an equivalence relation over it.  We can think of this categorically via the concept of a "groupoid".  A groupoid is a category where every morphism has an inverse such that `f . (inv f) = id` and `(inv f) . f = id`.

Why does this capture the idea of an equivalence relation?  Well, an equivalence relation must be reflexive, but this is just the categorical claim that it has identity arrows, and it must be transitive, but this is just composition, finally it needs to be symmetric (which is why we added inverses).

The ordinary notion of equality in mathematics on any set thus gives rise to a groupoid structure: namely one where the only arrows are the identity arrows!  This is often called the "discrete category".

It is left as an exercise to the reader to show that all functions are functors between discrete categories.

If you take this idea seriously, you begin to wonder about types with "equalities" that are not just identity.  This would allow us to encode "quotient types."  What is more, the groupoid structure has some more axioms (associativty, etc) that are claims about "equality of equality proofs" which leads down the road of n-groupoids and higher category theory.   This is cool stuff, although to be usefull you need dependent types and some not fully worked out bits, and when it finally makes it into programming languages should allow

```
data Rational where
    Frac :: Integer -> Integer -> Rational
    SameRationa :: (a*d) ~ (b*c) -> (Frac a b) ~ (Frac c d)
```

Such that every time you patterned matched you would also have to match on the extra equality axiom and thus prove that your function respected the equivalence relation on `Rational`
But don't worry about this.  The take away is just that the "Discrete category" interpretation is a perfectly good one.

### Denotational Approaches

Every type in Haskell is inhabited by an extra value, namely `undefined`.  What is going on with this?  Well, we could define a partial order on each type related to how "defined" a value is, such that

```
forall a. undefined <= a
```

but also things like

```
forall a a' b b'. (a <= a') /\ (b <= b') -> ((a,b) <= (a',b'))
```

Undefined is less defined in that it refers to value that doesn't terminate (actually, the `undefined` function is implemented by throwing an exception in every haskell, but lets pretend it was `undefined = undefined`.  You can't be sure something does not terminate.  If you are given an `undefined` all you can do is wait and see.  Thus, it *could be* anything.

A partial order gives rise to a category in a standard way.

Thus, every type gives rise to a category where the values are objects in this way.

Why are functions functors?  Well, a function *can't tell* it has gotten an `undefined` because of the halting problem.  As such, it either has to give back an `undefined` when it encounters one, or it has to produce the same answer no matter what it was given.  It is left to you to show that really is a functor.

Answer (score 11):

While there are some other, quite wonderful, answers here they all miss your first question somewhat. To be clear, values *simply do not exist* and *have no meaning* in the category Hask. That's just not what Hask is there to talk about.

The above seems a bit dumb to say or feel, but I bring it up because it's important to note that category theory provides just one lens for examining the much more complex interactions and structures available in something as sophisticated as a programming language. It's not fruitful to expect all of that structure to be subsumed by the rather simple notion of a category. [1]

Another way of saying this is that we're trying to analyze a complex system and it's sometimes useful to *view it as a category* in order to seek out interesting patterns. It's this mindset that lets us introduce Hask, check that it really forms a category, notice that `Maybe` seems to behave like a Functor, and then use all of those mechanics to write down coherence conditions.

```
fmap id = id
fmap f . fmap g = fmap (f . g)
```

These rules would make sense regardless of whether we introduce Hask, but by *seeing* them as simple consequences of a simple structure we can discover within Haskell we understand their importance.

---

As a technical note, the entirety of this answer assumes Hask is actually "platonic" Hask, i.e. we get to ignore bottom (`undefined` and non-termination) as much as we like. Without that almost the entire argument falls apart just a bit.

---

Let's examine those laws more closely since they seem to almost run against my initial statement---they're patently operating at the value level, but "values don't exist in Hask", right?

Well, one answer is to take a closer look at what a categorical functor is. Explicitly, it's mapping between two categories (say C and D) which takes objects of C to objects of D and arrows of C to arrows of D. It's worth noting that in general these "mapping"s are not categorical arrows—they simply form a relation between the categories and do not necessarily share in structure with the categories.

This is important because even considering Haskell `Functor`s, endofunctors in Hask, we have to be careful. In Hask the objects are Haskell *types* and the arrows are Haskell *functions* between those types.

Let's look at `Maybe` again. If it's going to be an endofunctor on Hask then we need a way to take all *types* in Hask to other *types* in Hask. This mapping is not a Haskell function even though it might feel like one: `pure :: a -> Maybe a` doesn't qualify because it operates at the *value* level. Instead, our object mapping is `Maybe` itself: for any type `a` we can form the type `Maybe a`.

This already highlights the value of working in Hask without values---we really do want to isolate a notion of `Functor` which doesn't depend on `pure`.

We'll develop the rest of `Functor` by examining the arrow mapping of our `Maybe` endofunctor. Here we need a way to map the arrows of Hask to the arrows of Hask. Let's for now assume that this is *not* a Haskell function—it doesn't have to be—so to emphasize it we'll write it differently. If `f` is a Haskell function `a -> b` then Maybe[`f`] is some other Haskell function `Maybe a -> Maybe b`.

Now, it's hard to not skip ahead and just start calling Maybe[`f`] "`fmap f`", but we can do a bit more work before making that jump. Maybe[`f`] needs to have certain coherence conditions. In particular, for any type `a` in Hask we have an id arrow. In our metalanguage we might call it id[`a`] and we happen to know that it also goes by the Haskell name `id :: a -> a`. Altogether, we can use these to state the endofunctor coherence conditions:

For all objects in Hask `a`, we have that Maybe[id[`a`]] = id[`Maybe a`]. For any two arrows in Hask `f` and `g`, we have that Maybe[`f . g`] = Maybe[`f`] . Maybe[`g`].

The final step is to notice that Maybe[_] just happens to be realizable as a Haskell function itself as a value of the Hask object `forall a b . (a -> b) -> (Maybe a -> Maybe b)`. That gives us `Functor`.

---

While the above was rather technical and complex, there's an important point in keeping the notions of Hask and categorical endofunctors straight and separate from their Haskell instantiation. In particular, we can discover all of this structure without introducing a need for `fmap` to exist as a real Haskell function. Hask is a category without introducing anything at all at the value level.

That's where the real beating heart of viewing Hask as a category lives. The notation that identifies endofunctors on Hask with `Functor` requires much more line blurring.

This line blurring is justified because `Hask` has *exponentials*. This is a tricky way of saying that there's a unification between whole bundles of categorical arrows and particular, special objects in Hask.

To be more explicit, we know that for any two objects of Hask, say `a` and `b`, we can talk about the arrows between those two objects, often denoted as Hask(`a`, `b`). This is just a mathematical set, but we know that there's another type in Hask which is closely related to Hask(`a`,`b`): `(a -> b)`!

So this is strange.

I originally declared that general Haskell values have absolutely no representation in the categorical presentation of Hask. Then I went on to demonstrate that we can do a whole lot with Hask by using *only* its categorical notions and without actually sticking those pieces inside of Haskell as values.

But now I'm noting that the values of a type like `a -> b` actually do exist as all of the arrows in the metalinguistic set Hask(`a`, `b`). That's quite a trick and it's exactly this metalinguistic blurring that makes categories with exponentials so interesting.

We can do a little better, though! Hask also has an terminal object. We can talk about this metalinguistically by calling it 0, but we also know of it as the Haskell type `()`. If we look at any Hask object `a` we know that there are a whole set of categorical arrows in Hask(`()`, `a`). Further, we know that these correspond to the values of the type `() -> a`. Finally, since we know that given any function `f :: () -> a` we can immediately get an `a` by applying `()` one might want to say that the categorical arrows in Hask(`()`, `a`) are *exactly* the Haskell *values* of type `a`.

Which ought to either be utterly confusing or incredibly mind-blowing.

---

I'm going to end this somewhat philosophically by sticking with my initial statement: Hask doesn't talk about Haskell values at all. It really doesn't as a pure category---categories are interesting precisely because they're very simple and thus don't need all these extra-categorical notions of types and values and `typeOf` inclusion and the like.

But I also, perhaps poorly, showed that even as a stricly *just a category*, Hask has something that looks very, very similar to all of the values of Haskell: the arrows of Hask(`()`, `a`) for each Hask object `a`.

Philosophically we might argue that these arrows aren't *really* the Haskell values we're looking for---they're just stand-ins, categorical mocks. You might argue that they're different things but simply happen to be in one-to-one correspondence with Haskell values.

I actually think that's a really important idea to keep in mind. These two things are different, they just behave similarly.

---

Very similarly. Any category lets you compose arrows, and so let's assume we pick some arrow in Hask(`a`, `b`) and some arrow in Hask(`()`, `a`). If we combine these arrows with category composition we get an arrow in Hask(`()`, `b`). Turning this all on its head a bit we might say that what I just did was find a value of type `a -> b`, a value of type `a`, and then combined them to produce a value of type `b`.

In other words, if we look at things sideways we can see categorical arrow composition as a generalized form of function application.

This is what makes categories like Hask so interesting. Broadly, these kinds of categories are called Cartesian Closed Categories or CCCs. Due to having both initial objects and exponentials (which require products as well) they have structures which completely model typed lambda calculus.

But they still don't have *values*.

[1] If you're reading this before reading the rest of my answer, then keep reading. It turns out that while it's absurd to *expect* that to happen, it actually kind of does. If you're reading this *after* reading my whole answer then let's just reflect on how cool CCCs are.

Comment: A nice discussion of exactly how fast you need to wave your hands to be able to treat Haskell types and functions as a category can be found [on the Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hask#.22Platonic.22_Hask) and a more formal treatment in [_Fast and Loose Reasoning is Morally Correct_](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-et-al-popl2006.html)

Comment: The wiki is where I got the phrase "platonic" :)

Comment: I've always heard that *Fast and Loose* conveys this rough idea, but I've never actually read the paper so I don't like recommending it personally.

Comment: "values simply do not exist and have no meaning in the category Hask" - can't we just take points of objects (global/generalized elements) as values?

Comment: @J.Abrahamson My comment was mostly for readers of your answer rather than for you. :)

Comment: @JJJ Yes, but that "taking as" is sort of a notational convenience and so that's mostly what I end up trying to motivation throughout this answer.

Comment: @JJJ The central and important point here is that category theory is not about values; its merit is in abstracting the values away. The fact that you can recover values using functions, or that some categories have sets as objects is besides the main point. PhilipJF's answer makes a lovely point about how you can make a type into a category using definedness. AndrewC's answer clarifies that a type that is a category is a different category to Hask, at a different level. This answer is an essential teaching point about what category theory is.I'll run out of rep for the bounties I want to give!

Comment: @chunksOf50 in my view the original question has a precise answer of where values fit in `Hask`, Haskell values are arrows from a terminal object in `Hask`, i.e. *global elements* (how category theory not about values then? ;)) of objects, we can just replace any `a :: A; a = ...; ... f[a] ...` with `a :: () -> A; a _ = ...; ... f[a()] ...` in Haskell and interpret this `a` as an arrow `1 -> A` in `Hask`. As usual, arrows is not just functions, but equivalence classes of them (by extensional equality), so that two functions `() -> A` which gives the same values is the same arrow in `Hask`.

Comment: It's like with, for example, subsets (subgroups, etc.). How would you define (generalized) subsets in category theory? You define them arrow-theoretically (as monomorphisms/subobjects). And how would you define (generalized) elements of objects? Well, again, as an arrow-theoretic construction (global/generalized elements). It's makes perfect sense and not abstracting away anywhere.

Comment: Also, see my answer again, we have an isomorphism `A ≊ Hom(1, A)` in (platonic) `Hask` too, so that hom-sets (which is internal in `Hask`) of global elements of types is isomorphic to its types. In category theory "isomorphic" usually means "the same", not just some notation trick, in my opinion.

Comment: @JJJ I mean "notation trick" to say that the notion of values inhabiting types and `(::)` in general isn't really captured in Category theory, though it may be encoded in it as we see in Hask. It's very, very interesting to see that this encoding is isomorphic to our notion of value/type, but if you erase that distinction before even breaking down the wall then you've reduced an interesting realization to triviality.

Comment: @JJJ So, to be clear, I don't disagree with you at all. The difference between your POV and mine is purely in didactics.

Comment: Yeah, I was answering to chunks. And you was making the same point about `Hom((), A)` in your answer, so there is no disagreements. And didactically‎... well, if you ask me for a value, say 2, I will give you `(+1 : N -> N) . (+1 : N -> N) . (0 : 1 -> N)` in `Hask` which is clearly an arrow `1 -> N` and obviously right here (well, but you said about that too). So it is like "there is no values in Hask" and then "bam! here is the values!"  :)

Comment: @JJJ Yes, but you could just have well said that types are sets and your construction is indeed isomophic to elements, but the beauty and power of category theory lies in the object/morphism abstraction. From a learning point of view, you need to leave the points behind for a while and concentrate on the objects, morphisms, functors, natural transforms etc, just as when learning Haskell you need to leave imperative behind for a while and concentrate on functions, types, polymorphism etc. It's not that you can't do points (or state), it's just not the main new idea. You're technically right.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to put things in terms of categories. Specially programming languages, that turn out to be very rich constructions.

If we choose Hask category, we're just setting a level of abstraction. A level where is not so comfortable to talk about values.

However, constants can be modeled in Hask as an arrow from the terminal object () to the corresponding type.
Then, for example:

- True : () -> Bool
- 'a' : () -> Char

You can check: Barr,Wells - Category Theory for Computing, section 2.2.

Answer (score 4):

Any category with a terminal object (or with terminal object*s*) has so-called [global elements](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/global+element) (or *points*, or *constants*, also [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_element), more can be found, for example, in the Awoday's [book](http://carlossicoli.free.fr/A/Awodey_S.-Category_theory-Oxford_University_Press,_USA%282010%29.pdf) on Category Theory, see *2.3 Generalized elements*) of objects which we can call *values* of this objects here, taking global elements as a natural and universal categorical notion for "values".

For example, `Set` has usual elements (of sets, objects of `Set`) as global elements, which means that elements of any set `A` can be viewed as [different](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/function+extensionality) functions (morphisms of `Set`) `{⋆} → A` from a [unit set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_%28mathematics%29) `{⋆}` to this set `A`. For a finite set `A` with `|A| = n` there are `n` such morphisms, for an empty set `{}` there is no such morphisms `{⋆} → {}` in `Set`, so that `{}` "has no elements" and `|{}| = 0`, for singleton sets `{⋆} ≊ {+}` uniquely‎, so that `|{⋆}| = |{+}| = 1`, and so on. Elements or "values" of sets are really just functions from a singleton set (`1`, terminal object in `Set`), since there is an isomorphism `A ≊ Hom(1, A)` in `Set` (which is `CCC`, so that `Hom` is internal here and `Hom(1, A)` is an object).

So that global elements is a generalization of this notion of elements in `Set` to any category with terminal objects. It can be generalized further with [generalized elements](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+element) (in a category of sets, posets or spaces morphisms are determined by actions on points, but it's not always the case in a general category). In general, once we turn "values" (elements, points, constants, terms) to arrows of a category in question we can reason about them using [the language](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic) of this particular category.

Similary, in [`Hask`](http://www.cs.gunma-u.ac.jp/~hamana/Papers/cpo.pdf) we have, e.g., `true` as `⊤ → Bool` and `false` as `⊤ → Bool`:

```
true :: () -> Bool
true = const True

false :: () -> Bool
false = const Frue
```

`true ≠ false` in a [usual sence](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/function+extensionality), also, we have a family of `⊥`'s as `⊤ → Bool` (`undefined`, `error "..."`, `fix`, general recursion and so on):

```
bottom1 :: () -> Bool
bottom1 = const undefined

bottom2 :: () -> Bool
bottom2 = const $ error "..."

bottom3 :: () -> Bool
bottom3 = const $ fix id

bottom4 :: () -> Bool
bottom4 = bottom4

bottom5 :: () -> Bool
bottom5 = const b where b = b

...
```

`⊥ ≠ false ≠ true` and this is it, we can't find any other morphisms of the form `⊤ → Bool`, so that `⊥`, `false` and `true` is the only values of `Bool` which can be distinguished extensionally. Note that in `Hask` any object has values, i.e. inhabited, since there are always morphisms `⊤ → A` for any type `A`, it makes `Hask` different from `Set` or any other non-trivial `CCC` (its internal logic is kinda boring, this is what *Fast and Loose Reasoning is Morally Correct* paper about, we need to look for a subset of Haskell which has a nice `CCC` with a sane logic).

Also, in Type Theory values are syntactically represented as terms which again [has](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/term#categorical_semantics) similar categorical semantics.

---

And if we talk about "platonic" (i.e. total, `BiCCC`) `Hask`, then here is a trivial proof of `A ≊ Hom(1, A)` in Agda (which captures that platonic traits well):

```
module Values where

open import Function
open import Data.Unit
open import Data.Product
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

_≊_ : Set → Set → Set
A ≊ B = ∃ λ (f : A → B) → ∃ λ (f⁻¹ : B → A) → f⁻¹ ∘ f ≡ id × f ∘ f⁻¹ ≡ id

iso : ∀ {A} → A ≊ (⊤ → A)
iso = const , flip _$_ tt , refl , refl
```