# Why Functor class has no return function?

Tags: math, haskell, monads, functor, category-theory

From categorical point of view, functor is pair of two maps (one between objects and another between arrows of categories), following some axioms.

I have assumed, what every Functor instance is similar to mathematical definition i.e. can map both objects and functions, but Haskell's `Functor` class has only function `fmap` which maps functions.

Why so?

**UPD** In other words:

Every Monad type `M` has an function `return :: a -> M a`.

And Functor type `F` has no function `return :: a -> F a`, but only `F x` constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by "situation is completly opposite for `Functor` and for `Monad` classes"? Since monads _are_ functors, it can't be opposite. — As for "why category theory argument is applicable to Haskell type theory": type theory has nothing to do with this whatsoever. It's just the _Haskell standard libraries_, they implement type classes which are _modelled after category theory concepts_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, and I wonder why they are opposite, despite the fact that they can not (:


The point is that I was thinking 'return' is part of mathematical functor mapping objects of Hack. But really return is representing  natural tranformation, which is defined for every Monad.

Comment: In category theory, a functor maps two things: objects to objects and arrows to arrows. In Haskell, a functor also maps two things: values to values and types to types.

Comment: Exactly, `return` is representing the natural transformation _η_: 1 → _T_, which is defined for every monad but not for general functors. So... what's still not clear to you?

Comment: @DavidYoung "values to values and types to types" ???

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, that is exactly that I had not understand. Now everything is clear, just SO is locking.

Comment: In `instance Functor f where ...`, `f` is something that takes a type and gives you another type (so it is a mapping between types). For example `Maybe` is a type constructor that takes a type and gives you a type. If you give it `Int`, then it gives you `Maybe Int`. `fmap` maps `f a` values to `f b` values given a function `a -> b`.

Comment: @DavidYoung "fmap maps f a values to f b values given a function a -> b." interpretation is unclear to me, and is not related to mathematical definition. Why it is beter than just think fmap as map of arrows of Hask?

Comment: I didn't word that very well. `fmap` takes a function from `a -> b` and maps it to a function from `f a -> f b`. As I understand it, this is analogous to the arrow mapping done by category theoretic functors. It takes an arrow in the category Hask, and it maps it to an arrow in the category Hask where all types have an `f` applied to them. So in the `Maybe` example, it maps arrows from Hask to the category of Haskell types where all types are applied to `Maybe`: `fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Maybe a -> Maybe b)`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two levels: types and values. As objects of Hask are types, you can map them only with type constructors, which have the `* -> *` kind:

- `α -> F α` (for `Functor F`),
- `β -> M β` (for `Monad M`).

Then for a functor you need a map on morphisms (i.e. functions, which are values):

```
fmap :: (α -> β) -> (F α -> F β)
```

The important thing is that `return :: α -> M α` of `Monad` is not a mapper of a type `α` to the `M α` as you might think. According to the mathematical definition of a monad, **`return` corresponds to a natural transformation** from `Id` functor to the `M` functor. And the `Id` functor is kind of implicit in Hask. The standard definition of a monad also requires another natural transformation `M ◦ M -> M`. So translating it to Haskell would look like

```
class Functor m => Monad m where
    return :: Id α -> m α
    join :: m (m α) -> m α
```

(As a side-note: these two natural transformations are actually the unit and multiplication, which make monad a *monoid in the category of endofunctors*)

The actual definition differs, but is equivalent. See [Haskell/wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Category_theory/Monads) on that.

If you take the composition-like operator derived from the standard bind `>>= :: m α -> (α -> m β) -> m β`:

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (α -> m β) -> (β -> m γ) -> (α -> m γ)
f >=> g = \a => f a >>= g
```

You can see, that it's all actually about the [Kleisli category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kleisli+category). See also the [article on nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad+%28in+computer+science%29) about monads in computer science.

Answer (score 8):

Objects of a category are *not* the same as objects in a OO programming language (we prefer to call those *values* in Haskell; what they mean in category theory was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380379/where-do-values-fit-in-category-of-hask)). Rather, the objects of **Hask** are *types*. Haskell `Functor`s are endofunctors in **Hask**, i.e. associate types to types, by the following means:

> Prelude> :k Maybe
>   Maybe :: * -> *
>   Prelude> :k Int
>   Int :: *
>   Prelude> :k Maybe Int
>   Maybe Int :: *

OTOH, the *arrows* of **Hask** are in fact values, of some function type `a -> b`. These are associated in the following way:

```
fmap :: ( Functor (f ::   t     ->     f t       {- type-level  -} ) )
             =>         (a->b)  ->  fmap(a->b)   {- value-level -}
                     ≡  (a->b)  ->  (f a->f b)
```

Comment: Yes, that is definitely what's i am talking about. 

Functor consists of two morphisms, but in Haskell one of them is simply function and another is type-level entity.

Comment: That's not quite correct. If you'd like to see functors as _morphisms_, then it's just one: in the category of categories, the objects are categories and a morphism between category _A_ and category _B_ is a functor that maps objects of _A_ to objects of _B_ as well as morphisms of _A_ to morphisms of _B_. In the example, `Maybe` is an endofunctor of **Hask**, i.e. an endomorphism in the category of categories, and as I said it maps objects to objects (e.g. the _type_ `Int` to type `Maybe Int`) and morphisms to morphisms (`length :: String -> Int` to `fmap length :: Maybe String -> Maybe Int`)

Answer (score 7):

Though you were using those fancy categorical terms in your question and should be completely satisfied with the existing answers, here is an attempt for a rather trivial explanation:

Suppose there *would* be a function `return` (or `pure` or `unit` or `...`) in the Functor type class.

Now try to define some common instances of Functor: `[]` (Lists), `Maybe`, `((,) a)` (Tuples with a left component)

Easy enough, eh?

Here are the ordinary Functor instances:

```
instance Functor [] where
   fmap f (x : xs) = f x : fmap xs
   fmap _ []       = []

instance Functor Maybe where
   fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
   fmap _ Nothing  = Nothing

instance Functor ((,) a) where
   fmap f (x, y) = (x, f y)
```

What about `return` for Functor now?

Lists:

```
instance Functor [] where
   return x = [x]
```

Alright. What about Maybe?

```
instance Functor Maybe where
   return x = Just x
```

Okay. Now Tuples:

```
instance Functor ((,) a) where
   return x = (??? , x)
```

You see, it is unknown which value should be filled into the left component of that tuple. The instance declaration says it has a type `a` but we do not know a value from that type. Maybe the type a is the `Unit` type with only one value. But if its `Bool`, should we take `True` or `False`? If it is `Either Int Bool` should we take `Left 0` or `Right False` or `Left 1`?

So you see, if you had a `return` on Functors, you could not define a lot of valid functor instances in general (You would need to impose a constraint of something like a FunctorEmpty type class).

If you look at the documentation for `Functor` and `Monad` you will see that there are indeed instances for `Functor ((,) a)` but not for `Monad ((,) a)`. This is because you just can't define `return` for that thing.

Comment: Exelent addition! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you have

```
instance Functor F where
    fmap = ...
```

Then the type constructor `F` is the action on objects (which are types) taking a type `T` to the type `F T`, and `fmap` is the action on morphisms (which are functions) taking a function `f :: T -> U` to `fmap f :: F T -> F U`.

Comment: But why there is no special function, like in the case of monads?

Comment: What do you mean?  The case of monad is no different.

Comment: Every Monad type M has an function return :: a -> M a.

But functor type F has no function return :: a -> F a.

Comment: That doesn't map objects to objects though.  In category theory terms, its a morphism.

Answer (score 0):

In category theory, a functor maps all the objects from a category to another, but a functor doesn't map *the elements in the objects*.