# In the declaration of class Functor, can the type variables be function types?

Tags: haskell, types, functor, applicative

In Haskell, the class `Functor` is declared as:

```
class   Functor f   where
fmap    ::  (a  ->  b)  ->  f   a   ->  f   b
```

Can  type variables `a` and `b` be  function types, or must they be non-function types?

If they can be function types, isn't it that class `Functor` become effectively the same as class `Applicative`, in terms of making `fmap` able to apply to functions with arbitrary number of arguments? According to what *Programming in Haskell* by Hutton says:

> Functors  abstract    the idea    of  `fmap` mapping  a   function    over    each    element of  a   structure.  Applicatives generalize this    idea    to  allow   `fmap` mapping functions    with    any number  of  arguments   to  be  mapped, rather  than being  restricted  to  functions   with    a   single  argument.

In applicative:

> ```
> fmap0 ::  a   ->  f   a
> fmap0 =   pure
> fmap1 ::  (a  ->  b)  ->  f   a   ->  f   b
> fmap1 g   x   =   pure    g   <*> x
> fmap2 ::  (a  ->  b   ->  c)  ->  f   a   ->  f   b   ->  f   c
> fmap2 g   x   y   =   pure    g   <*> x   <*> y
> fmap3 ::  (a  ->  b   ->  c   ->  d)  ->  f   a   ->  f   b   ->  f   c   ->  f   d
> fmap3 g   x   y   z   =   pure    g   <*> x   <*> y   <*> z
> ```

Class `Applicative` is declared as:

> ```
> class Functor f   =>  Applicative f   where
> pure  ::  a   ->  f   a
> (<*>) ::  f   (a  ->  b)  ->  f   a   ->  f   b
> ```

Thanks.

Comment: `a` and `b` can be function types.

Comment: Then what can applicatives do that functors can't? See my update

Comment: An applicative needs to have a `pure` thing, something to "wrap it in an `Applicative`). It is not said that this is possible.

Comment: What does "It is not said that this is possible" mean? I am also still wondering about my previous comment.

Comment: Your implementation of `fmap1` uses `Applicative` methods. This shows that just having `Applicative` is enough to implement `Functor`. But your question asks the other way: is just having `Functor` enough to implement `Applicative`? I think if you try to go the other way -- try to write down implementations of `pure` and `(<*>)` just using `fmap` (and pure things) on the right-hand side -- you will find yourself stuck quite quickly indeed.

Comment: See also: [Good examples of Not-a-Functor/Functor/Applicative/Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7220436/791604)?

Comment: The fact that `b` can be a function type is why `Applicative` exists: `fmap (+) (Just 3) == Just (+3)`. `Applicative` is what lets you apply the result of a partial application of `+` to another `Just` value. `fmap (+) (Just 3) <*> Just 5 == Just (+3) <*> Just 5 == Just 8`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`a` and `b` can be function types. They can be any type. In fact, a valid `Functor` *must* allow them to be any type.

To answer your `Applicative` question, let's try it.

```
fmap :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f (b -> c)
```

Okay, great! Now I can take an `f a` and convert it to a `f (b -> c)`. But.... then what? I can't apply `f (b -> c)` to an argument. It's not a function; it's a value of my functor type. If only we had a function with this signature...

```
superFmap :: f (b -> c) -> f b -> f c
```

But that sure does look a lot like

```
(<*>) :: f (b -> c) -> f b -> f c
```

which is a member of `Applicative`. Hence, we need `Applicative` to be able to apply this secondary result.

What the other answers said is correct. We can't implement `pure` either, for similar reasons. But it's important to note that we can't even get `(<*>)` in general, because if we could then that would imply that every `Functor` is [`Apply`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.3.2/docs/Data-Functor-Apply.html#t:Apply), which is also certainly not the case.

Answer (score 12):

> Can type variables `a` and `b` be function types

– yeah, sure.

> isn't it that class `Functor` become effectively the same as class `Applicative`

no, absolutely not. If you insert a function type into the `a` or `b` of the `fmap` signature, you get things like

```
fmap :: ((x -> y) -> b) -> f (x -> y) -> f b
```

or

```
fmap :: (a -> p -> q) -> f a -> f (p -> q)
```

but crucially, `fmap` always takes exactly one `f _` wrapped-value and spits out exactly one such value. `Applicative` meanwhile allows you to accept *any number* of wrapped values, provided you give it the a function to process the contained values.

Comment: Thanks. In my post, is it correct that `fmap0` and `fmap1` form a endofunctor on the category of types? What do `fmap0`, `fmap1`, `fmap2`, ... form?

Comment: No. Functors are formed by a mapping of objects (i.e. types) and one of morphisms (i.e. of functions). `fmap1` is indeed a mapping of functions, but `fmap0` is a mapping of _values_, not of types. In the `Functor` class, the mapping of objects is implicit: it's the type constructor `f` itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33442135/745903, also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647659/why-functor-class-has-no-return-function

Answer (score 5):

> Can type variables `a` and `b` be function types, or must they be non-function types?

`a` and `b` can be *any* type, so function types as well.

For example we can use:

```
fmap (+) [1,4,2,5]
```

Here `(+)` has type:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b       ) -> f a -> f b
(+)  :: Num c =>      c -> (c -> c)
```

So here `b ~ c -> c`, and `b` is thus a function.

An example where `a` is a function is:

```
fmap ($ 2) [ (1+), (2*), (3-) ]
```

here we have as types:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a        -> b) -> f a -> f b
($ 3)  :: Num c =>    (c -> d) -> d
```

So `a ~ (c -> d)` here, here we thus apply `3` to all functions in the list.

Note that we did not add extra `fmap` definitions here (as in `fmap1`, `fmap2`, ...). It is just the fact that `a` can be substituted with a type `c -> d`, etc.).

> If they can be function types, isn't it that class `Functor` become effectively the same as class `Applicative`.

No, since it is for example not said that `pure` can be implemented for a given `Functor`. Immagine that you for example make a data type:

```
type Owner = String

data Owned a = Owned Owner a
```

then `Owned` can be implemented to be an instance of `Functor`:

```
instance Functor Owned where
    fmap f (Owned o x) = Owned o (f x)
```

But implementing a `pure :: a -> Owned a` is not possible: why would be the owner of the object?