# Understanding Haskell Type Signatures

Tags: haskell, types, type-signature

I am in the process of teaching myself Haskell and I was wondering about the following type signatures:

```
Prelude> :t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
Prelude>
```

How should I interpret (no pun intended) that?

A semi-similar result is also proving to be puzzling:

```
Prelude> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'll start with `map`.  The `map` function applies an operation to every element in a list.  If I had

```
add3 :: Int -> Int
add3 x = x + 3
```

Then I could apply this to a whole list of `Int`s using `map`:

```
> map add3 [1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

So if you look at the type signature

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

You'll see that the first argument is `(a -> b)`, which is just a function that takes an `a` and returns a `b`.  The second argument is `[a]`, which is a list of values of type `a`, and the return type `[b]`, a list of values of type `b`.  So in plain english, the `map` function applies a function to each element in a list of values, then returns the those values as a list.

This is what makes `map` a *higher order function*, it takes a function as an argument and does stuff with it.  Another way to look at `map` is to add some parentheses to the type signature to make it

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

So you can also think of it as a function that transforms a function from `a` to `b` into a function from `[a]` to `[b]`.

---

The function `($)` has the type

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

And is used like

```
> add3 $ 1 + 1
5
```

All it does is take what's to the *right*, in this case `1 + 1`, and passes it to the function on the *left*, here `add3`.  Why is this important?  It has a handy *fixity*, or operator precedence, that makes it equivalent to

```
> add3 (1 + 1)
```

So whatever to the right gets essentially wrapped in parentheses before being passed to the left.  This just makes it useful for chaining several functions together:

```
> add3 $ add3 $ add3 $ add3 $ 1 + 1
```

is nicer than

```
> add3 (add3 (add3 (add3 (1 + 1))))
```

because you don't have to close parentheses.

Comment: are there any practical differences between `add3 $ add3 $ add3 $ add3 $ 1 + 1` and `add3 . add3 . add3 . add3 $ 1 + 1`?

Comment: If the signatures `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` and `(a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])` are equivalent, does that mean `->` is right-associative?

Comment: @Ryan That's correct, the function arrow is right associative.  `a -> b -> c -> d ~= a -> (b -> (c -> d))`, but `((a -> b) -> c) -> d` can't be reduced any further.

Comment: I'm confused why the arguments to $ are to the left and right of it like `add3 $ 1 + 1`. Why isn't it `$ add3 1 + 1`?

Comment: @gary69 The `$` operator could be used in prefix notation, but it'd look like `($) (add3 1) 1`, but that isn't particularly useful.  `$` is an operator function, just like `+` or `>>=`.  Its usefulness is from its operator precedence, and it does nothing but help you write cleaner code. It has `infixr 0`, which is the lowest precedence.  This longer explanation might help explain better too https://typeclasses.com/featured/dollar.

Answer (score 7):

`($)` is just function application. It gets a function of type `a->b`, an argument of type `a`, applies the function and returns a value of type `b`.

`map` is a wonderful example for how reading a function type signature helps understanding it. `map`'s first argument is a function that takes `a` and returns `b`, and its second argument is a list of type `[a]`.
So `map` applies a function of type `a->b` to a list of `a` values. And the result type is indeed of type `[b]` - a list of `b` values!

`(a->b)->[a]->[b]` can be interpreted as "Accepts a function and a list and returns another list", and also as "Accepts a function of type `a->b` and returns another function of type `[a]->[b]`". 
When you look at it this way, `map` "upgrade" f (the term "lift" is often used in this context) to work on lists: if `double` is a function that doubles an integer, then `map double` is a function that double every integer in a list.

Comment: Is the fact that a -> b is enclosed in parentheses significant? It appears to indicate precedence.

Comment: You are right! The arrow is right-associative, so a->b->c is equal to a->(b->c) - that's a function that takes an argument of type a and returns another function of type b->c. If you want a function as an argument, you'll need the parentheses.

Comment: Yes it is significant. The precedence is usually right to left, such that `f :: a -> b -> c` and `f :: a -> (b -> c)` are equivalent. This is really because Haskell functions can be partially applied (applying f to some a returns a function from b to c). When `g :: (a -> b) -> c` is used instead, it's specifically denoting that you must apply a function to g, and that you can't partially apply g.

Comment: Thanks for the help all. In an effort solidify my understanding, if someone wrote: map (*2) [1..50] and examined the type signature for map, (a -> b) corresponds to the map function and the (*2) respectively? The [a] is the list from 1 to 50, and the [b] is the result? It appears as though we're forcing left associativity with the parentheses. (a -> b) returns a function that accepts a list of type 'a' and returns a list of type 'b'? Would that be an accurate interpretation?

Comment: `(a -> b)` corresponds to `(*2)`, since `a` and `b` are `Int` in our example, and `(*2)::Int -> Int`.
`(a -> b)` is a function that accepts a single value of type `a` and returns a single value of type `b`.
But `map (*2)`, due to partial application, is of type `[a]->[b]` - accepts a list of `a` and returns a list of `b`.

Comment: Added some more info to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Well, as said already, `$` can be easily understood if you just forget about currying and see it like, say, in C++

```
template<typename A, typename B>
B dollar(std::function<B(A)> f, A x) {
  return f(x);
}
```

But actually, there is more to this than just applying a function to a value! The apparent similarity between the signatures of `$` and `map` has in fact a pretty deep category-theory meaning: both are examples of the morphism-action of a functor!

In the category **Hask** that we work with all the time, objects are types. ([That is a bit confusionsome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380379/where-do-values-fit-in-category-of-hask), but don't worry). The morphisms are functions.

The most well-known (endo-)*functors* are those which have an instance of [the eponymous type class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Functor). But actually, mathematically, a functor is only something that maps both objects to objects and morphisms to morphisms<sup>1</sup>. `map` (pun intended, I suppose!) is an example: it takes an object (i.e. type) `A` and maps it to a type `[A]`. And, for any two types `A` and `B`, it takes a morphism (i.e. function) `A -> B`, and maps it to the corresponding list-function of type `[A] -> [B]`.

This is just a special case of the functor class signature operation:

```
fmap :: Functor f   =>   (a->b) -> (f a->f b)
```

Mathematics doesn't require this `fmap` to have a name though. And so there can be also the *identity functor*, which simply assigns any type to itself. And, every morphism to itself:

```
($) :: (a->b) -> (a->b)
```

"Identity" exists obviously more generally, you can also map values of any type to themselves.

```
id :: a -> a
id x = x
```

And sure enough, a possible implementation is then

```
($) = id
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Mind, not *anything* that maps objects and morphisms is a functor... it does need to satisfy the [functor laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Definition).