# how do you read the ramda docs?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm having trouble understanding the signature of Ramda [docs](http://ramdajs.com/docs). For example if you look at `map` you see this

`Functor f => (a → b) → f a → f b`

I don't see how this pattern fits the example:

```
var double = x => x * 2;

R.map(double, [1, 2, 3]); //=> [2, 4, 6]
```

The functor in this example is `[1,2,3]`, so how does that get placed into the signature of `f` in `Functor f => (a → b) → f a → f b`? Also, what do the `→` mean?

Comment: Better ask here: https://gitter.im/ramda/ramda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give a brief answer here, but a more complete one is spread across two answers to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361059), which in turn was taken from the [Ramda wiki page](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Type-Signatures).  (Disclaimer: I'm the author of that page and one of the principals in Ramda itself.)

This is broken into two parts:

```
Functor f => (a → b) → f a → f b
```

Before the fat arrow (`=>`) we have constraints on the remainder.  The single constraint in this example is that the variable `f` must be a [`Functor`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#functor).  A Functor is a type whose members have a `map` method which obeys certain laws.  And the declaration is parameterized over another type, so we don't write just `f` but `f String`, `f Number`, or more generically, `f a` for some unknown type `a`.

The skinny arrow (`->`) is an abbreviation for the type Function.  So instead of writing

```
Function x y
```

we can instead write

```
x -> y
```

or when needed to avoid ambiguity.

```
(x -> y)
```

Putting these together, we can note that in `R.map(double, [1, 2, 3])`, we have a function (`double`) from `Number` to `Number`, which means that our `a` and `b` are both `Number`.  And our functor is `Array`.  So specializing the definitions with these types, we have `map` accepting a function from `Number` to `Number`, and returning a function that takes an array of `Number`s and returns a new array of `Number`s.  (That's because in this system, `->` binds to the right, so `(a -> b -> c)` is equivalent to `(a -> (b -> c))`.  In Ramda, all functions are curried in such a way that you can call them with any initial set of parameters, and until all the terms have been supplied, you continue to get back functions.  Thus with Ramda functions there is no real difference between `R.map(double)([1, 2, 3])` and `R.map(double, [1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: Is `Function x y` just the same as `function x ( ) {y}`?

Comment: No, `Function x y`, and its shorthand `x -> y`, represent a function that accepts a parameter of type `x` and returns one of type `y`.  `function(str) {return str.length;}` has type `Function String Int` or more concisely, `String -> Int`.

Comment: Why does propEq have the signature of `String → a → Object → Boolean` when it accepts 2 strings as an argument and returns a boolean? Shouldn't it be `string, string` -> boolean`?

Comment: `propEq('foo', 42, {foo: 42, bar: 52}) //=> true`.  And `propEq('foo', 42, {foo: 52, bar: 42}) //=> false`.  The first argument has to be a String (although perhaps it should extend to also allow Symbols).  The second argument is of arbitrary type (here a number, but anything is allowable.)  The third must be an object.  It returns a boolean.  That signature looks correct.

Comment: How do I know what is finally being returned? In the example before you mentioned that `->` binds right  so `(a -> b -> c)` is equivalent to `(a -> (b -> c))`, but for propEq it seems like `String → a → Object → Boolean` is equivalent to `(String → a → Object) → Boolean`

Comment: Ramda's version of curry in means that these are all equivalent : `propEq('x') (42)(obj)`, `propEq('x')(42, obj) `, `propEq('x', 42)
 (obj)`, and `propEq('x', 42, obj)`.   All the intermediate forms are (curried) functions. If the final output is also a function, it would be wrapped in parentheses: `comp :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`  takes two functions and returns a third.

Comment: As to what's finally being returned, perhaps the easiest way to state it is that it's what's to the right of the last arrow not contained in parentheses.