# What is the ~> in a functor explanation?

Tags: javascript, functor, ramda.js

I'm trying to understand Ramda docs so I looked up what a functor is [here](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#functor), but what is the `~>` in this mean?

```
map :: Functor f => f a ~> (a -> b) -> f b
```

Comment: There's a short answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435656, and much, much more detail at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361059.

Answer (score 2):

It's already written there :

**Type signature notation**

> ~> (squiggly arrow) Method type constructor. When a function is a
>   property of an Object, it is called a method. All methods have an
>   implicit parameter type - the type of which they are a property. a ~>
>   a -> a is a type satisfied by methods on Objects of type a which take
>   a type a as an argument and return a value of type a.

Comment: if the first `f` is a functor, what is the `f` in front of `a` and `b`?

Comment: The initial bit (`Functor f =>`) is a constrain the the remaining part of the definition.  `f` can represent any Functor type, such as lists (really arrays): `map:: [a] ~> (a -> b) -> [b]`, (Note that because lists are so common, there is a shorthand for `Array x`: `[x]`.)  Or Maybe: `map: Maybe a ~> (a -> b) -> Maybe b`. or Future: `map :: Future a ~> (a -> b) -> Future b`.  Ramda's versions don't deal with *methods*, only *functions*, so these change a bit there, e.g. `map:: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.  But its the same principle.

Comment: All `f`s represent the same type constructor (or parameterized type). The first appearance of `f` just says that the type constructor `f` has a functor constraint, i.e. instances of `f` must define a suitable `map` operation. What's probably confusing you is that the given type signature just annotates the generic version of this `map` operation. So instances of `f` need a `map` operation and `map` itself expects an instance of `f` as its second argument.